# same .htacces - multiple parked domains - same root folder - redirect to language link

Tags: .htaccess, lang

I have multiple domains.

```
domain.com
domain.dk
domain.ro ... etc
```

All are pointed to the same root folder via Parked Domains. So .htaccess file is the same for all.

Also is have a  php language script and a php currency script witch help users changing the language via session variables.
The link looks like this: `index.php?lang=en&currency=USD` (this are default session variables 'en' AND 'USD' ).

How can i setup .htaccess so when somebody click on www.domain.dk to redirect to ?

```
www.domain.dk/index.php?lang=da&currency=DKK
```

How can i setup .htaccess so when somebody click on www.domain.ro to redirect to ?

```
www.domain.ro/index.php?lang=ro&currency=RON
```

etc ...

Thank you. 
Florin

Comment: I don't think you can do exactly what you are asking to do. Because .htaccess can't see your session variables, there is no way to check if the default language has been set or not. The only option I can think of (although unreliable) would be to check the HTTP_REFERER, if it doesn't match your domain, then the user came from elsewhere and should be redirected. That being said, it might be better to just have the index.php script set the defaults automatically.

Comment: The session variable is set before page is loaded. By default is 'us' and 'USD'. So if any domain is loaded this variable are loaded by default. But removing HTTP_REFERER i can redirect to proper link with .htacces and Garben solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.dk$
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?lang=da&currency=DKK [QSA]

#repeat for .ro
```

Comment: Thank you Gerben. Seams like proper condition. Redirect link is ok. but something is strange. I got ERROR: "The page isn't redirecting properly". Checking if the link is right link.

Comment: Yes the link is OK. Works without condition.

Comment: I had a script -->  $referer  = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; header("Location: $referer"); // go back to the page we came from. I comment this and everything is OK . THANK YOU VERY MUCH.